$f$ be continuous, with f holomorphic and $ Re(f)|_{\partial G} = c $. Show that $f$ is constant.
Problem:
Let ( G ) be a bounded domain, and let $\ f: \bar{G} \to \mathbb{C} $ be continuous, with $ f|_G $ holomorphic and $ \operatorname{Re}(f)|_{\partial G} = c $ for some constant $ c $. The goal is to show that $ f $ is constant.
Idea:
We can use the maximum/minimum principle. The problem is that even though ( f ) is constant on the boundary, the minimum principle does not yet directly imply that ( f ) is constant, as it could be zero.
Let $ g(z) = \exp(f(z)) $. On the boundary, we have:
$
|g(z)| = |\exp(f(z))| = \exp(\operatorname{Re}(f(z))) = \exp(c).
$
Thus, on $ \partial G $, $ g(z) $ is constant.
Now, applying the maximum/minimum principle to $ g(z) $, we conclude that $ g(z) $ must also be constant inside $ G$.
My feeling is that :
Since $ g(z) $ is constant and $ g(z) = \exp(f(z)) $, this implies that $ f(z) $ must be constant as well.
However, I am struggling to formalize this last argument rigorously and to complete the proof. I would appreciate help with this last step.

Math must be enclosed in $ ... $, not in \( ... \)

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Oh, I have corrected it:)

try $\frac{d}{dz}g(z)$

So your question is why $g$ being constant implies that $f$ is constant? In that case it is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/791242/42969

The function $u={\rm Re} f(z)$ satisfies the mean value property (which follows from the Cauchy integral formula for $f$) $$ u(x,y)={1\over 2\pi }\int\limits_0^{2\pi}u(x+r\cos t,y+r\sin t)\,dt$$ provided that the ball with radius $r$ centered at $(x,y)$ is contained in $G.$ Therefore $u$  satisfies the maximum as well as the minimum principle. Hence $u$ is constant in $G.$ The C-R conditions imply that $v={\rm Im} f(z)$ is constant as well. Hence $f=u+iv$ is constant.

But with the minimum principle we get that f is constant or that f(z)=0. Because of this we need g=exp(f(z))

The function $u$ cannot admit extreme values in $G$. Therefore $c\le u\le c $ in $\overline{G}.$ There is no need to consider $e^f.$

But the minimum principle says that if $ |f| $ has a local minimum at a point $ z_0 $, then $ f(z_0) = 0 $ or $ f $ is constant. So it doesn't directly tell us that $f $ is constant; we would need $h = \exp(z) $ to prevent that.

I do not care about $|f|.$ I concentrate on $u={\rm Re} f.$ This function satisfies the maximum and minimum value principle.

ah ok, thank you!:)
